# Laravel Routes Regular Expression start with @ character

Tags: regex, laravel

I need to create a route that responses to any string starting with '@' character. Routes like following examples :

```
www.mywebsite.com/@john  
www.mywebsite.com/@jack  
www.mywebsite.com/@something
```

So I wrote:

```
Route::get('{something}','SomeController@someMethod')->where('something','/@^/');
```

But when I test it, I face 404 not found found page.

what is the correct regular expression for this?

Comment: Try `->where('something','/^@.*/')`. Or maybe just swapping the start of string `^` anchor with `@` will suffice.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not working

Comment: Try removing the `/` delimiters. `->where('something','^@')`

Comment: Removing / fixed it.

Comment: Great. Note the `@^` pattern means `@` should be followed with the beginning of string, and it is not possible, the pattern just never matches. `'^@'` asserts the position at the start of the string, and only there does it try to match `@`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Route::get('/{tag}', 'SomeController@someMethod')->where('tag', '^@.*');
```

Answer (score 2):

This will also work:

```
Route::get('@{something}', 'SomeController@someMethod');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this

```
Route::pattern('tag', '@[a-zA-Z]');

Route::get('{tag}', 'SomeController@someMethod');
```

This way you seperate the logic of the regex and the route and it will work as you want

Answer (score 0):

Note the `@^` pattern means `@` should be followed with the beginning of string, which is not possible, and the pattern never matches any string. The `'^@'` pattern asserts the position at the start of the string, and only there does it try to match `@`.

Also, the usual `/` regex delimiters should be removed from this pattern as they are treated as part of the pattern here.

So, in your case you may just swap the anchor and the `@` char:

```
Route::get('{something}','SomeController@someMethod')->where('something','^@');
```